# Caching aspect - how to create key from method name and arguments

Tags: caching, hashtable

I am creating an aspect to apply to methods that checks the cache for a return value, and only permits procession onto the logic of the method if the cache is empty or stale.

I need to generate a cache key for the storage of this information that is unique to the method call for a given set of arguments. My initial hunch is to implement a key creation algorithm that takes the qualified method name and appends serialised argument information.

Is there a recognised approach to key creation under these circumstances?

Comment: I am currently concatenating the ToString results for the arguments. I am concerned about the fragility of this approach with reference type arguments.